# How to make javascript code only for Devices with(max-width=520px)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply this JS code only to devices with Maxwidth=520px I don't really know how, any help?

```
// for max-width = 520px
const myBtn = document.getElementById("darktheme");
const body = document.body;
const welcome = document.getElementById("txtt");

let isDarkTheme = false;

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme; 

  if (isDarkTheme) {   
    body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17, 17, 17)";
    body.style.color = "white";
    welcome.style.color = "white";
  } else {    
    body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    body.style.color = "black";
    welcome.style.color = "white";
  }
});
```

Comment: The question is moot - you need to be using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) for this, not JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method in JavaScript. It returns a MediaQueryList object which we can use to determine the media query string.

I've modified your code with the above in mind see my comments:

```
const myBtn = document.getElementById("darktheme");
const body = document.body;
const welcome = document.getElementById("txtt");

let isDarkTheme = false;

// define MediaQueryList
let mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 520px)");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Check if MediaQueryList's condition is met
  if (mql.matches) {
    isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme; 

    if (isDarkTheme) {
      body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(17, 17, 17)";
      body.style.color = "white";
      welcome.style.color = "white";
    } else {
      body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      body.style.color = "black";
      welcome.style.color = "white";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks bro this is so useful but i need someelse now that i have this for max-width 520px i have literaly the same code with some changes i want to apply to min-width 700px if u show me how i will accept ur answer

Comment: what i want u to do is the exact code the max-width stays dont remove it and when the min width is 600px make the welcom.style.color="black"

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like for the min-width 700px, though if its simialar as you said, then checking for `let mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)");` and then doing something based on that condition (for example if (mql) { ... }) should work the same way